# Outline of the proof that Tamagawa number, $[E (K): E_0 (K)]$ is finite

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, neron-models

I have a question about proof that Tamagawa number, $[E (K): E_0 (K)]$ is finite.
Could you please tell (correct) me any strange parts about my understanding of the outline of the proof ?

My understanding (outline)

"The elliptic curve $E$ on the local field $K $($R$ is an ring of integers) is the Neron model ( There is a group scheme on $SpecR$ that has $E / K$ as a generic fiber), and if it is $ε$, then $E (K) / E_0 (K)$ is isomorphic to $ε (R) / ε_0 (R)$ as a scheme. Furthermore, since $K$ is a Hansel field, $ε (R) / ε_0 (R)$ is isomorphic to $ε'(R) / ε'_0 (R)$ (where $ε'$ is a special fiber of $ε$ and $ε'_0$ is an connected component of $ε'$ which contains identity element).
Since the algebraic group $ε'_0$ is a connected component containing the identity element of the algebraic group ε', by using the algebraic group theorem “**If $G$ is an algebraic group, then the connected component of $G$ including the identity element is a subgroup with a finite index** ", we can conclude that it is a subgroup of a finite index.

**The algebraic group theorem cannot be used for the original $E (K) / E_0 (K)$. This is because $E_0 (K)$ is not connected unless $E_0(K)＝E (K)$. Therefore, the algebraic group theorem can be applied via the Neron model and its special fiber. "**

Comment: Exercise VII.6 in Silverman gives an elementary method to prove that they are finite, but you need to analyse the equation modulo higher powers of the maximal ideal to find the index - and the best way to do that is by Tate's algorithm. The best way to formulate it is using Néron models. The more interesting question is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404621/ .

Comment: Elementary proof only applies when residue field is finite. In Silverman ( and in this question), residue field is finite is not supposed. And I'm asking whether my understanding of the method using Neron model is correct, not asking what kind of other method are there.

Comment: You say "local field" so I assumed the residue field is finite. You deleted the statement that is is hard to prove, which my first comment was about. Your last paragraph does not make sense. What topology do you put on $E(K)$ and $E_0(K)$? Note there is no $K$-variety $E_0$ whose $K$-rational points are $E_0(K)$. It is just a subgroup of $E(K)$, so clearly the "connected component" argument can't work over $K$, you need $R$ and hence the Néron model.

Comment: You really should not post the same question on both at the same time. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260219/outline-of-the-proof-that-tamagawa-number-e-k-e-0-k-is-finite

Comment: Topology is natural one defined by $v$ on projective space and it's relative topology. Could you explain me more why $E_0(K)$ cannot be considered as $K$-variety ?

Comment: $E$ is an irreducible curve defined over $K$. Anyway, I recommend to learn basic algebraic geometry: You can't take $R$-valued point of the special fibre, $E(K)/E_0(K)$ is not a scheme, just an abelian group. etc Your "understanding (outline)" above reveals that you confuse a few few things even if you are on the right track to learn it. I think questions like this are more appropriate for math.stackexchange than here.